# iOS NSLog error with Unicode characters

Tags: objective-c, ios, unicode, nsstring, nslog

Can anyone tell me the cause of the discrepancy for the following results ?

```
completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"\n placemarks%@", placemarks);
```

Resulting:

```
placemarks(
"\U039b\U03b5\U03c9\U03c6\U03cc\U03c1\U03bf\U03c2 \U039a\U03cd\U03c0\U03c1\U03bf\U03c5 163, 16451 \U0391\U03c1\U03b3\U03c5\U03c1\U03bf\U03cd\U03c0\U03bf\U03bb\U03b7\U03c2, \U0395\U03bb\U03bb\U03ac\U03c2 @ <+37.90085408,+23.75654648> +/- 100.00m, region (identifier <+37.90085408,+23.75654648> radius 141.62) <+37.90085408,+23.75654648> radius 141.62m"
)
```

and

```
for(id object in placemarks ) {NSLog(@"%@ \n", object);}
```

Resulting

```
2012-09-14 13:08:23.493 ΑΦΜ[1390:c07] Λεωφόρος Κύπρου 163, 16451 Αργυρούπολης, Ελλάς @ <+37.90085408,+23.75654648> +/- 100.00m, region (identifier <+37.90085408,+23.75654648> radius 141.62) <+37.90085408,+23.75654648> radius 141.62m
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Interesting :)

Passing `%@` into `NSLog`'s format string just means 'call `description` on an object'.

It looks like `description` on `NSArray` deals with unicode characters differently than the `description` on each object.

However, I suspect that the description method on `NSArray` just calls description on each of the objects it contains and then, for some reason I'm not 100% sure about, is encoding them before dumping them out to `NSLog`.

Answer (score 3):

Passing `%@` to `NSLog` does call the `[NSArray description]` on the array. [NSArray class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/description) says that `[NSArray description]` "returns a string that represents the contents of the array, formatted as a property list". Doing so converts unicode characters to `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding`. Your NSArray will print correctly if you reverse the process.

```
completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithCString:[[placemarks description] cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding]);
```

This works by converting the original string with all of the \Uxxxx encoded universal characters into a c string, then decoding the c string to an `NSString` reversing the `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` which had been done by the `[NSLog description]`. I have not figured out a way to do this without first converting to a c string.